# Can't see parameters using dataset with crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, parameters, crystal-reports, dataset

I've been dealing with this problem for more than 6 months, when I create a dataset and inside de dataset I call a stored procedure and then call this dataset into my report (crystal reports) I can't see the parameter fields:

[image]

I try to create the parameters in a sqlcommand and then add the parameters to my report using
rpt.setParameters("@a","sample");
but I got an error.

What could I do? please help me, I'm very desperated and angustied with this

My code (Sorry if it's in spanish) :

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("prd_generarReporteOP", cn) 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idop", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("idop"))
cmd.Parameters.Add("@producto", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ""      
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter da.SelectCommand = cmd 
Dim ds As New DataSetOP da.Fill(ds, "DataSetOP")
```

Comment: which parameters you expecting? `stored procedure` parameters??

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting stored procedure parameters, please help me, I'm desperated with this, thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your data source. Since you using the the `dataset` as the datasource you already getting the filtered results.

You need to use the `stored-procedure` as your data source and then the parameters will appear

Comment: I've already do this, see my code (Sorry if it's in spanish) :
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("prd_generarReporteOP", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idop", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("idop"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@producto", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ""
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim ds As New DataSetOP
        da.Fill(ds, "DataSetOP")